# How to drop columns in Oracle7

Tags: oracle

How to drop a table column in Oracle7?
Yes, yes... My client still uses this version: Oracle7 Server Release 7.3.4.5.0

Or... how to change column datatype from Varchar2 to Long... in Oracle7 Server Release 7.3.4.5.0

Comment: In Oracle 7 you cannot drop columns, This function was added in Oracle 8. Your are not really asking how to convert a column to `LONG`...

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit:It was implicit what I want: convert a column to LONG. One approch used is to create a new LONG column, update the values, DROP original column and rename the new one. Then, recreate indexes and constraints.That's why the reason of my question. I started working in Oracle world from version 9i... But thanks for your time.

Comment: LOBs weren't added until 8 either so if you need more than 2000 chars then `LONG` is your only option I guess. But those can't be indexed or have constraints (except not-null), and [have many other restrictions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SQL73/ch2.htm#sqllrmsclong).

Comment: @AlexPoole: Yes... I know all of that. I'm generalizing. To others datatypes maybe we need that. But my case is: convert varchar2 to LONG. Drop column is not a solution. I have one that I will put here.

Comment: If you don't want the old column there any more then your only option, I think, is to recreate the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
--1. Create a clone table.
CREATE TABLE tableA_aux
AS
   SELECT *
   FROM tableA;

/

-- 2. Alter table to accept null values (if is not nullable)
ALTER TABLE tableA MODIFY text varchar2(2000);

-- 3. Clear table column
UPDATE tableA
SET text = NULL;

COMMIT;

-- 4. Alter datatype to VARCHAR2 -> LONG
ALTER TABLE tableA MODIFY text LONG;


--5. Update the column with original values
UPDATE tableA s
SET s.text =
       (SELECT a.text
        FROM tableA_aux a
        WHERE a.PK_ID = s.PK_ID);

COMMIT;
```